# calculate the mean of a column based on the label in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Actually I am new to python and am facing some problems with the pandas dataframe. I want to find out the mean of the columns that have a label positive. I have three columns x1, x2 and label. I want to find out the mean of x1 which have the label 'positive'. I have used a pandas dataframe which looks like this. Can someone help me with this.

```
        x1  x2     label
 0       5   2  positive
 1       6   1  positive
 2       7   3  positive
 3       7   5  positive
 4       8  10  positive
 5       9   3  positive
 6       0   4  negative
 7       1   8  negative
 8       2   6  negative
 9       4  10  negative
 10      5   9  negative
 11      6  11  negative
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['label'].eq('positive'),'x1'].mean()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at `df.loc[]` after filtering with `df['label'].eq('positive')`:

```
df.loc[df['label'].eq('positive'),'x1'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) as follows:

```py
df.loc[df['label'] == 'positive', 'x1'].mean()
```

or alternatively

```py
df.loc[df['label'].isin(['positive']), 'x1'].mean()
```

The boolean indexing array is `True` for the correct clusters. `x1` is just the name of the column to compute the mean over.